# Assert.Equal is not working with dates

Tags: c#, .net-core, mstest

I have written a simple test method to verify a method that converts a long value to DateTime, following is the code...

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void ConvertToDateTime_TestMethod()
    {
        long date = 1500024370374;

        DateTime result = date.GetDateTime(); 
        DateTime comparisonDate = new DateTime(2017, 07, 14, 9, 26, 10);
        Assert.AreEqual(result, comparisonDate);
    }
```

Point is that both date and time values are exactly same (also verified in watch window) why does it gives this exception? I found [this](https://automatetheplanet.com/assert-datetime-mstest-nunit/) article that uses a delta to compare if minor time difference is failing the comparison but still unsure why I still need an extra function to compare date/time assertions.

Edit-1: Here is my date conversion method which I am testing

```
    public static DateTime GetDateTime(this long milliseconds)
    {
        try
        {
            return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(Convert.ToDouble(milliseconds));
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }
```

Even though there is an alternate to this with new datetime(long), but logically whats wrong with this?

Comment: What is `date.GetDateTime()` here? That's not a standard framework method. Are you sure the two dates are in the same timezone? Equal down to the millisecond?

Comment: Yeah, please post the extension method.

Comment: added my extension method

Comment: There's no way the code you show can compile, the extension returns a nullable datetime but your test isn't nullable.

Comment: isn't this extension method the same as new DateTime(long)

Comment: Its compiling and also used nullable date assignment

Comment: 374 milliseconds difference in these times.

Comment: Dont think the question deserves downvotes though. It has code, it describes a problem.

Comment: @Jamiec It probably did in it's initial revision though

Comment: From .NET 4.6 onwards: `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds`. And extension methods on system types like `long` are in poor taste. Pre-.NET 4.6, you want `.AddTicks` with an appropriate conversion factor, not `.AddMilliseconds` -- the conversion to `double` loses precision for large values.

Comment: For this to work, your `long` value should be `1500024370000`, as you clearly have additional 374 milliseconds.

Comment: @DavidG please reconsider your down wote, it was compling even with nullable DateTime.

Comment: @ak1 First you should not beg for votes in either direction. Secondly I didn't vote on this at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the nearest second (the granularity the console is showing you) they are equal. To the nearest millisecond, they are not

```
long date = 1500024370374;
DateTime result = new DateTime(1970,1,1).AddMilliseconds(date);
DateTime comparisonDate = new DateTime(2017, 07, 14, 9, 26, 10);

Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fffff"));
// 14-07-2017 09:26:10.37400
Console.WriteLine(comparisonDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fffff"));
// 14-07-2017 09:26:10.00000
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/PYDLAD6594